# How to convert mime encoding (us-ascii to utf-8) recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have few `us-ascii` encoded files. I want to convert them to `utf-8` recursively.

To find the files I am using the command

```
find . -name "*.adoc" -type f -exec file --mime-encoding {} \; | grep -v ": us-ascii"
```

The output looks like

```
./sds.adoc: us-ascii
./docker/misc/terms.adoc: us-ascii
./docker/misc/tools.adoc: us-ascii
./docker/basics-containers.adoc: us-ascii
./web-scraping/links.adoc: us-ascii
./system-design/reference-architecture.adoc: us-ascii
./system-design/replication vs load balancing.adoc: us-ascii
./system-design/performance.adoc: us-ascii
./system-design/links.adoc: us-ascii
./system-design/disaster-recovery.adoc: us-ascii
```

To convert, i guess, i have to use `iconv -f us-ascii file.adoc -t UTF-8 -o file.adoc`

I am not understanding how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. US-ASCII covers only  the characters U+0000 to U+007F, and the encoding of those is the same in US-ASCII as it is in UTF-8 (the byte value corresponds to the Unicode code point (0x41 byte for the U+0041 character (`A`) for instance)).

So you have nothing to do. Your files are already in UTF-8.

`file` reports us-ascii, because from the small subset it looked at, it looked like text, it had no byte value above 0x7f and likely¹ the distribution of characters being used suggested it was more likely to be ASCII than other 7bit charsets like EBCDIC.

Running `iconv -f us-ascii -t UTF-8` on those would be counter productive, as at best it does nothing, at worse you lose data because if `file` got it wrong and there were byte values above 0x7f (for characters above U+007F encoded in UTF-8 or some other charset) in the part it didn't look at, `iconv` will abort there with an error, leaving an incomplete file.

---

<sup>¹ as a guess, you'd want to look at the libmagic code to see what heuristic it uses to guess text file charsets, which in general is something that can't be determined reliably.</sup>

Comment: Is it also true for WINDOWS-1258, WINDOWS-1252, ASCII etc. Which types are subset of UTF-8 and is useless to try to convert to UTF-8.

Comment: @blueray, no windows-1258  and 1252 are not subsets of UTF-8 (though they are supersets of ASCII like most charsets still in use these days). There is no single-byte charset other than ASCII that is a subset of UTF-8 as the UTF-8 encoding of characters other than the ASCII one is on 2 bytes or more. the codepoint of iso8859-1 characters are the same as in Unicode (for 0..0xff), but again the UTF-8 encoding of the 0x80...0xff ones are different between iso8859-1 and UTF-8

Comment: `iconv -f WINDOWS-1258 -t UTF-8` and `iconv -f WINDOWS-1258 -t UTF-8` does not work in my machine. But `iconv -f ISO-8859-3 -t UTF-8` converts ISO-8859-3 to UTF-8. What might be the reason?

Comment: In which way does it not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry, it is actually working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
find . -name '*.adoc' -type f -execdir sh -c '
  for f; do
    file --mime-encoding "$f" | grep -qi us-ascii &&
      bn="$(basename "$f" .adoc)" && 
      iconv -f us-ascii "$f" -t UTF-8 -o "$bn-utf8.adoc"
  done' sh {} +
```

This will `cd` into each directory containing `.adoc` files and, (for each .adoc file in that directory) if `file` indicates that the file is us-ascii, use `iconv` to convert it to utf-8 (with a different output filename).

NOTE: The `-execdir` option is non-standard and requires either the GNU or BSD versions of `find`.  GNU is standard on Linux.

---

If you want to replace the original us-ascii file with the utf-8 version, add  `&&` to the end of the `iconv` line and add the following line immediately after it:

```
  mv "$bn-utf8.adoc" "$f"
```

Comment: btw, if you want to test what this will do (highly recommended for any commands that some complete stranger on the internet tells you to run), add `echo ` or, better yet, `printf "%s\n"`, before `iconv`.  That will show you what it *would* do without actually doing it...a dry-run.

Comment: The `-utf-8` files created are not utf-8 encoded.

Comment: that's kind of a problem with your input files and what you want to do with them (which is mostly pointless, at best, as SC shows), not a problem with the "how do i do something with/to a bunch of files I found with find" problem you asked about.

Comment: I modified your code a bit and it has been very helpful. Not sure who downvoted the answer. However, Stéphane Chazelas's answer actually addressed the issue that "US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8" and it is useless to try to convert and `iconv` actually can not do it. So, I accepted that answer.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it was either a "fan", or someone who didn't understand either your question or my answer.  And while it's nice to get upvotes, it's not much of a motivator for me (in part because I long ago maxed out the reputation "privileges" that a high rep score on U&L can give me). I answer questions that interest me in some way, expending as much effort as I feel the answer requires at the time.  Some get upvoted, some don't.  Answers that take me hardly any effort or thought tend to get far more upvotes than answers I put time and research effort into.